# module 'tensorrt' has no attribute 'Logger' for TensorRT version 5.1.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, object-detection, tensorrt

I was trying to use TensorRT while inferencing on `Mobilenet v2` OD model. The `Tensorflow` version is `1.15.0` and `Cuda` version is `10.0`. The NVIDIA TensorRT package is `nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1804-cuda10.0-trt5.1.5.0-ga-20190427_1-1_amd64.deb`. The `TensorRT` version is `5.1.5.0-1+cuda10.0`. I have tried out from all github, NVIDIA and stackoverflow resources.

```
import tensorrt as trt
uff_model_path = "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/frozen_inference_graph.uff"
engine_path = "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/ssd_mobilenet_v2_bs_1.engine"
TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.WARNING)
trt.init_libnvinfer_plugins(TRT_LOGGER, '')
```

Error Log:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-651d430e77b0> in <module>()
      1 uff_model_path = "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/frozen_inference_graph.uff"
      2 engine_path = "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/ssd_mobilenet_v2_bs_1.engine"
----> 3 TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.WARNING)
      4 trt.init_libnvinfer_plugins(TRT_LOGGER, '')
      5 

AttributeError: module 'tensorrt' has no attribute 'Logger'
```

Please point me at the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: I had similar problems in the past. What helped was to install `tensorrt` with the `tar` file in a clear `venv`. You might want to try that

Comment: I am using colab for this inference right now. Anyway I will try it.

Comment: @neko No success after trying from within of venv.